# IQR of continuous random variable

Tags: probability

If the continuous random variable $X$ has probability density
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \sec^2 x, & 0<x<\dfrac\pi4, \\[8pt] 0, & \text{otherwise,}  \end{cases}
$$
find the interquartile range of $X$

So the integral is $\tan(x)$. I'm not sure how to work out the IQR though - I tried $3/4 \times \pi/4$ and $1/4\times\pi/4$ as bounds and got $0.469$ after evaluating the integral. The answer is $0.399$.

How do I work out the IQR from CRVs?

Comment: You take the the x value corresponding cumulative distribution  value of 0.75 and subtract it from the x value corresponding to 0.25. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have $\Pr(X\le x) = \tan x$ for $0\le x\le\pi/4$.

You want $\Pr(X\le x_1)= 1/4$.  So $\tan x_1= 1/4$ and $x_1=\arctan\dfrac14$.  Do a similar thing with $3/4$ and the range you seek is
$$
\arctan\frac34-\arctan\frac14.
$$
I don't know if you  can do anything better than using numerical methods after that.

(Using R, I get $0.3985224$.  That is of course rounded.)

Comment: @DilipSarwate : I'm afraid your point escapes me.  Why would we care about $\tan(A-B)$?  If we assume you meant $B=\arctan(1/4)$, we would get $\tan(A-B)=8/19$, so I could have used the software to find $\arctan(8/19)$ instead of $\arctan(3/4)-\arctan(1/4)$, but I don't see that anything is gained by doing it that way instead of the way I did it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: With $A = \arctan(3/4), B = \arctan(1/4)$, $$\tan(A-B) = \frac{\tan(A) - tan(B)}{1+\tan(A)\tan(B)}$$ gives $$\tan(\arctan(3/4)-\arctan(1/4))=\frac{3/4-1/4}{1+(3/4)(1/4)}=\frac{8}{19}$$  Thus, $$\arctan\frac 34 - \arctan \frac 14 = \arctan \frac{8}{19}$$ which requires only a single look-up in an arctan table.

Comment: I suppose if I had used a table this might be slightly more convenient, except that $8/19$ would probably first get rounded.

Comment: As an engineer (and not a mathematician) who has had to design devices that carry out such calculations, I would always look for techniques that would save some effort. Yes, using one table lookup instead of two is not that important from a mathematical viewpoint...

Comment: OK .... I really wasn't thinking of efficiency of algorithms.