# Arctangents, Fibonacci numbers, and the golden ratio

Tags: trigonometry, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

In the course of doing scratchwork to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954459/iqr-of-continuous-random-variable), I had occasion to write the trigonometric identity
$$
\arctan x- \arctan(1-x) = \arctan\left( \frac{1-2x}{x^2-x-1} \right).
$$
Now notice that this is
$$
\arctan\left( -\frac{d}{dx} \log(x^2-x-1) \right)
$$
and $x^2-x-1$ is the monic polynomial of lowest degree with rational coefficients that has the golden ratio $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ as a root, and that number is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} F_{n+1}/F_n$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Googling indicates that someone has found connections between arctangents and Fibonacci numbers: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibpi.html#section2

Is the fact I state above "known"?  What related facts are "known"?  (Scare quotes because obviously it is *known* to those who read this question.)

Comment: I dont see any interesting  "fact" just accidental coincidence.

Comment: @Leox : An accidental coincidence in mathematics may be an occasion to develop it into an interesting "fact". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Leox : BTW, did you name yourself after this guy?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Leo_X ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Of cource, but  right now I still dont see such an interesting "fact". Moreover I like such "fact" $$ \arctan\left( -\frac{d}{dx} \log(x^2-x-1) \right)=\arctan\left( i^2\frac{d}{dx} \log(x^2-x-(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))) \right)$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy What about the domains? The identity is only true for a certain interval?

Comment: @imranfat : Yeah ... sometimes that kind of thing feels like nitpicking and I neglect it.  Prob'ly a mistake not to attend to that.....  Anyway, in the cited problem it was appropriate to think only of $0\le x\le1/2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I personally doubt the the golden ratio here got to do something with it. More coincidental I think, but maybe it is useful for something. This problem is a good exercise for entry calc students to practice derivatives and see when and how the identity holds. Now if I "replace" for example $1-x$ by $t$, and sub away $x$,then I obtain a new identity for the next semester students....