# A series with Fibonacci numbers and the golden ratio

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

How can we prove this identity:
$$\sum _{n=1}^\infty\arctan\frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^{2n+1}} = \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt5 \, \phi ^{4 n-2} \, (2n-1) \, F_{2n-1}},\tag{$\diamond$}$$
where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers, and $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ is the golden ratio?

Numerically, both sides look the same:
$$-0.1668065238140974961621200570365353119855145764209454554444463...$$

Comment: Some known series with the Fibonacci numbers in the denominator: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html

Comment: Surely you can provide some more context as to how you got to this identity?

Comment: @orlp Found it accidentally when studied connection between the fibonorial and q-factorial ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonorial#Connection_with_the_q-Factorial)) and numerically checked some conjectures about their asymptotic behavior. The left-hand side is actually $\arg \left[1/2\right]_{-\phi^{-2}}!$.

Comment: Might be slightly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/955903/19661 and http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibpi.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using the power series expansion of $\arctan(x)$ at $x=0$ (note that $|(-1)^n/\phi^{2n+1}|<1$), we have that
\begin{align*}
\sum _{n=1}^\infty\arctan\frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^{2n+1}}&=
\sum _{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+k}\frac{\phi^{-(2k+1)(2n+1)}}{2k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\phi^{-(2k+1)}}{2k+1}\sum _{n=1}^\infty (-\phi^{-(4k+2)})^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\phi^{-(2k+1)}}{2k+1}\cdot \frac{-\phi^{-(4k+2)}}{1+\phi^{-(4k+2)}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}\phi^{-(6k+3)}}{2k+1}\cdot \frac{\phi^{2k+1}}{\phi^{(2k+1)}-(-\phi^{-1})^{2k+1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}\phi^{-(4k+2)}}{2k+1}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}F_{2k+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}\phi^{-(4n-2)}}{(2n-1)F_{2n-1}}.
\end{align*}